# Stop DOM event when other is active?

Tags: javascript

I'm making my own video player with JS. I was wondering how can I only have the contents of `timeupdate` only running when the `input` listener is not active? `document.getElementById('progress')` is a input type of range slider as well. The `input` listener code only runs when you're actively dragging it and only stops running the even once you let go of the slider.

```
<div class="center">
    <video id="video" src="video1.mp4" width="100%" preload="metadata" autoplay controls muted></video>
    <input id="progress" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" width="100%">
</div>


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var video = document.getElementById('video')
    var progress = document.getElementById('progress')

    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
        progress.max = video.duration
    })

    video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
        progress.value = video.currentTime
    })

    progress.addEventListener('change', function() {
       var seek = video.duration * (progress.value / 100)
       video.currentTime = seek
    })

    progress.addEventListener('input', function() {
      console.log('woo')
    })

})
```

Comment: Why do you have two identically `id`d elements? And, where is the accompanying HTML?

Comment: I mean, you could do something simple like add a flag that you set to true when the `input` event listener is active, then check that flag in `timeupdate`.

Comment: Yea besides @MikeMcCaughan's comment you could always remove the eventListener for `timeupdate` inside of the `input` listener;

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan this was my inital thought, but was hoping I'd be able to do it via another listener or something like the so.

Comment: So, one of things we like to know, in the question, is what you've tried previously, so that we don't waste our time telling you solutions you've already discarded...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan well I looked through about all the DOM events and didn't find anything that would work exactly the way I'd need it to. My initial thought on actually thinking about this before acting, I thought I was able to see if an event like `progress.addEventListener('input')` was active, but I didn't see any way to do that. Could I have an example of the variable flag? I'm not sure how I'd be able to set it to false after input is done.

Comment: `var flag = false; progress.addEventListener('input', function () { flag = true; /*do stuff */ flag = false; }); video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function () { if (flag) return; /* do other stuff */ });`

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan ah, I understand. For some reason I was thinking Async for some reason, so I didn't think that'd work but was just having a brain fart. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simplified `debounce` function for this.

The debounce function makes sure you're only calling a target function unless the debounced function has *not* been called in the last N milliseconds.

In your case, you want to disable `timeupdate` for as long as `input` is being called.

```
// Initial state: 'timeupdate' is enabled
var disableTimeupdate = false;

video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
    // don't do anything if 'timeupdate' is disabled
    if (disableTimeupdate) return;
    progress.value = video.currentTime
})

// Define debounced function.
// It will be called in the 'input' event handler
var debounceEnableTimeupdate = debounce(function() { 
    disableTimeupdate = false; 
}, 1000);

progress.addEventListener('input', function() {
  // Disable the timeupdate event
  disableTimeupdate = true;
  // Re-enable it if 'input' has not been triggered in the past second
  debounceEnableTimeupdate();
})
```

More details about `debounce` [on this page](https://davidwalsh.name/function-debounce)